# Min and max options in Flot not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

According to the flot documentation (https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md):

> "The options "min"/"max" are the precise minimum/maximum value on the
>   scale. If you don't specify either of them, a value will automatically
>   be chosen based on the minimum/maximum data values."

I am specifying min and max values, yet the graphs that are being generated are still automatically chosen based on the minimum/maximum data values (`var d1`) rather than the specified min and max values.

Here is my code:

```
var i = 0;
while (i < myarray.length) { // length of myarray is 3, hence 3 graphs are produced
        // generate date object from date and time strings in array
        startTime = new Date(myarray[i].date[0] +'T' + myarray[i].time[0] + ':00');

        // generate timestamp from date object
        startTime = startTime.getTime();

        endTime = new Date(myarray[i].date[1] +'T' + myarray[i].time[1] + ':00');
        endTime = endTime.getTime();

        var d1 = [[startTime, 0], [(((endTime - startTime)/2) + startTime), 1], [endTime, 0]];

        var options = { series: { curvedLines: { active: true }}};

        // min is the time 2014-11-20, 3 AM (timestamp: 1416453000000)
        // max is the time 2014-11-20, 11 PM (timestamp: 1416525000000)
        $.plot($("#" + i), [{data: d1, xaxis: {min: (new Date('2014-11-20T03:00:00')).getTime(), max: (new Date('2014-11-20T23:00:00')).getTime(), mode: "time", twelveHourClock: true, timeformat: "%I:%M"}, lines: { show: true}, curvedLines: {apply: true}}], options);

         i++;
        }
```

The graphs end up looking like this (notice all have different min and max values):

[image: Graph 1]

[image: Graph 2]

[image: Graph 3]

P.S. The Flot time series plugin doesn't seem to be working either since the x axis points are showing up as timestamps and not in the "hour:minutes" (`%I:%M`) format as specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at their [time example](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/examples/axes-time/index.html) they're putting the xaxis config in the options (so the third argument) and **not** included with the graph data (second argument) like you are:

```
$.plot("#placeholder", [d], {
            xaxis: {
                mode: "time",
                minTickSize: [1, "quarter"],
                min: (new Date(1999, 0, 1)).getTime(),
                max: (new Date(2000, 0, 1)).getTime()
            }
        });
```